# how to minify typescript in angular for deployment?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, gulp

I created a web app using angular 7, and now I want to deploy my website. I saw this video that said that minifying or uglifying the project will be good for deployment since it reduces download time. So the video showed gulp being used to minify the project but it was shown for javascript but not typescript? I would like to know, how can I minify my project for deployment?

this is what I have in my gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('minify', function() {
return gulp.src('src/app/**/**/*.ts')
.pipe(uglify())
.pipe(concat('webpage.min.js'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('/dist'));
});
```

gulp.task('default',["minify"]);

Comment: Why can't you use Angulars build process with`ng build` command? Why do you use gulp?

Comment: Please edit your question, remove either angularjs or angular

Comment: I'm using gulp so I can uglify and concat my typescript for deployment. Does ng build do the same?

Comment: Typically one transpiles TypeScript to JavaScript before minification. TypeScript cannot run natively in the browser.

Comment: Take a look at `gulp-typescript`. It would allow you to transpile your typescript to javascript. Would be a simple addition to your gulpfile

Comment: If you are a beginner, which I feel is the case, I suggest you to just use Angular-CLI instead of gulp, unless you want to do very specific things

Comment: What would be the difference in using angular-cli and gulp? And where can I find more resource of it?